# Why would SSRS have 2 instances of a top-level group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

In a report with two levels of grouping, I have a top-level group that is repeating.  This is apparent in the report on the left-hand navigation bar/document map but also when exporting to Excel, it splits to two worksheets (with the same name!) and shows on separate lines in the document map tab. 
E.g.

```
UNIT A
  person 1
  person 2
  person 3
UNIT B
  person 4
  person 5
UNIT B
  person 6
```

The desired behavior is

```
UNIT A
  person 1
  person 2
  person 3
UNIT B
  person 4
  person 5
  person 6
```

Any ideas for why the group would be splitting?

Comment: It's impossible for us to give a good answer with the limited amount of information you've provided. This could be caused by any number of problems. I'd start by checking the grouping and how that relates to the raw, returned data.

Comment: @Jacobm001: thanks for your response.  I would like to improve my question but am not sure how.  The groups are very straightforward - they're regular fields in the data.  Would it be helpful to post the query behind?

Comment: can you show the data which might be helpful and perhaps your layout of the report.. SSRS only changes group if there is a difference in value.. ensure there are no hidden characters or the likes in the UNIT B group

Comment: @Harry: Thank you!!  I just copy-pasted the query results into a text editor and looked at the hex values, there was a trailing space.  This never showed up because apparently when you query SQL Server, strings with a trailing space are equal to the string without the trailling space.  Can you post as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Glad to be of help :) have been caught out like this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS only changes group if there is a difference in value.. ensure there are no hidden characters or the likes in the UNIT B group.